# Dificuldade usando tasks e create_server juntos (asyncio)

Tags: python-3.x

Estou trabalhando em uma ferramenta que recebe conexões de dispositivos, lê suas mensagens e publica estas à uma fila do RabbitMQ.

Para as filas do RabbitMQ eu utilizei o aio_pika (pika mais simples) e criei 2 funções diferentes. Uma subscriber que fica lendo uma fila, e uma publisher que coloca mensagens em outra fila. Para executar e manter ambas em execução, eu utilizei o método `create_task`. Isso aparentemente funciona bem.

O meu problema é quando tento adicionar os "servidores" ao loop. A quantidade destes pode variar de ambiente para ambiente, então eu tenho uma API que me retorna uma lista de servidores que eu devo iniciar. O que eu estou tentando fazer é usar um loop para iniciar esses servidores com o método `create_server`.

Meus servidor nada mais é do que uma extenção do asyncio.Protocol...

Abaixo segue uma versão simplificada do meu código e o erro que tenho ao tentar executar o mesmo.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import json
import asyncio
from myapp import log, amqp
from myapp.protocol import test

LOG = log.create_logging_system('myapp')


def auth():
    # TODO: REQUEST!
    response = json.loads(
        '{"type":"auth","data":{"status":"valid","amqp":{"user":"myapp_cli","password":"password","virtual_host":"test"},"central":[{"name":"teste","port":"9090","protocol":"test"}]}}')
    
    return response['data']['central'], response['data']['amqp']


async def start_central_ip(port, loop, name, protocol):
    logger = log.create_logging_system(name)
    # Lambda to use arguments
    def central(n, l): return test.Central(name, logger)
    server = await loop.create_server(protocol_factory=central,
                                      host='0.0.0.0',
                                      port=port)
    await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #   Auth
    centrals, amqp_params = auth()
    #   Loop do Async
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    #   RabbitMQ
    rabbit_url = amqp.build_url(amqp_user=amqp_params['user'],
                                amqp_pass=amqp_params['password'],
                                virtual_host=amqp_params['virtual_host'])
    loop.create_task(amqp.consumer(rabbit_url))
    loop.create_task(amqp.publisher(rabbit_url))
    for central in centrals:
        protocol = central['protocol']
        start_central_ip(central['port'], loop, central['name'], protocol)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Error:

```
myapp.py:49: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'start_central_ip' was never awaited
  start_central_ip(central['port'], loop, central['name'], protocol)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```